# Change filename in zip

Tags: linux, zip

Currently I'm doing the following command in PHP

```
exec("zip -j -P pass $zipname $filename");
```

The thing is the `$filename` is something like `oawigufh.tmp` is there any way to have the file in the archive called something like `file.txt`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or programming at all, but with the zip program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a;

```
exec("mv $filename file.txt && zip -j -P pass $zipname file.txt");
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing that as it will overwrite the other file in the directory

Comment: So you want to keep a copy of all the .tmp files intact, with their old names, and also zip each of them into a different zip archive, but for them all to have the same name in each respective archive?

Comment: correct (space).

Comment: Yeah that *should* be an easy one...nothing in the zip man page mentions renaming. If you absolutely must achieve this, you're probably going to have to create a directory (probably using the tmp file name) and do your rename and zip in there. Then cleanup afterwards. I'd be tempted to make this 'work space' a ramdisk to avoid hitting the disks all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in Linux command line, I mean echo result string what you executed in `exec()` and past it in Linux command line.